# I need to install an old flash player that is not listed on the adobe site

Tags: firefox, plugins, flash-player

Anyone know where I can find Flash Player 11.0.1.152 for Firefox?

I can´t find it at the [Adobe site](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html#main_Archived_Flash_Player_versions_for_developers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Oldversion.org](http://www.oldversion.com/) seems to have that [specific version](http://www.oldversion.com/Macromedia-Flash-Player.html) - its a great resource for older versions of software.

Comment: Thanks. The plugin was not for firefox but I found it here: oldapps.com/flash_player.php

Comment: I hadn't thought of this site.  I routinely get that issue where a flash upgrade can't be installed due to improper removal of the old versions.

Comment: Phat!  Never heard of Oldversion.org... geek props for JG